# Swift 2.0 ContactsUI Framework

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, contactsui

I am working on a project in Swift 2.0 that requires me to use the IOS 9s ContactUI Framework. The issue that I am having is properly picking a phone number from the contacts list. When I select a phone number from a contact, the application crashes.

Here is the code that I am using to perform this task.

```
var delegate: NewLocationViewControllerDelegate!
var contacts = [CNContact]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}//end

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func openContacts(sender: UIButton) {
    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPicker.delegate = self;
    contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]

    self.presentViewController(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}//end

func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContactProperty contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {
    let contact = contactProperty.contact
    let phoneNumber = contactProperty.value as! CNPhoneNumber
    print(contact.givenName)
    print(phoneNumber.stringValue)
}//end
```

Comment: Crashes how? On what line, and with what message?

Comment: This is the error I get from the console Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}

Comment: This is in the simulator?

Comment: @matt yes its in the simulator, the screen goes black and the app crashes when you click on a phone number.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the tap on the phone number is trying to dial the phone - and on the simulator, there is no phone.

Your `contactPicker:didSelectContactProperty:` will never be called, because no phone number will ever be selected. Instead, tapping a phone number will try to dial that number. This is because you have not provided a `predicateForSelectionOfProperty`. You need to set the `predicateForSelectionOfProperty` to an NSPredicate that evaluates to `true` when the `key` is a phone number.

Comment: Think about what I'm telling you. Without an NSPredicate that returns `true` when the key is a phone number, you won't be able to select a phone number. Now go write that predicate and set the `predicateForSelectionOfProperty` to it.